# MySQL trouble shooting help, can't do anything on single table

Tags: mysql

Apologize but I really don't have much information for the question.

I have a single MySQL MySIAM engine table that's holding around 80K records (continually increase).
Today it's suddenly stop responding.

I can't even do a single query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1`), the server just spend time executing and look like will never stop.

I can't dump table to make backup.

However, another tables in the same database, same engine (MySIAM) are working just fine.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Not sure if it's DEADLOCK or anything.

All data in that table is really important. You direction pointing to help me identify the problem would be really appreciated. For example, are there any command to check table if it's corrupt by what reasons, etc.

---

UPDATE:::::
I can't use `CHECK TABLE` neither, it also take forever execution time.

UPDATE ::::
I did research and come up with something about REPAIR TABLE.
However, it's suggested that I should do the backup first.
As I can't do the back for this table, would it be OK to use the REPAIR command anyway?

---

### ::::::::::::: SOLVED :::::::::::

Follow Cristian's help, use `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` command. I see that there is a process with state 'Copying to tmp table' that hold another process.
So I use `KILL <process id>` to kill that process and everything released to normal.

Cheers
Chanon

Comment: Can you share the details of the Operating system that you are using are you using a 32 bit operating system ,If so I guess you may have memory map issue .

Comment: Can you run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and see if it gives you any more information regarding any deadlocks?

Comment: Hi Aravind,

I'm running MySQL 5.1 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2, 64-bit Operating Sytem.

This was happened before but for just about an hour, then eveything is back to normal (the same table).

However, it's already took 2 hours now and that single table still not response (I can view table structure's info but not its data).

Not sure if I can check if it does have issue with memory mapping?

Comment: HI InSane,

I'm this issued table is on MyISAM engine.
However, after run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command, there is no pending and no queue. Should this be fine?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I had a lockup as well

Answer (score 8):

Sorry but I can't comment your question... :)

Exactly which version of MySQL you run, 5.1.xx?

Can you post you `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` status?

**UPDATE**: Chanon, after this event, and to prevent this problem, you have to review and optimize the query that send MySQL in "Copying to tmp table" state, in order to avoid slowness and a risk of "disk full" for your temporary partition.

Comment: I Cristian,

There are around 100 records listed almost of them have state as 'Locked'. All with command 'Query'. Anything I can do to resolve this?

Please note that after State "Copying to tmp table" everything is locked up.

Comment: You have to find the older query in NON Locked state like "sending data" or "freeing items" or other state, find it and paste the status if you can. Then can you specify the exact mysql version? and... in addition, can you post your "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%cache%';"

Comment: Hi Cristian, after state 'Copying to tmp table', everything is lock up. Can I just delete that process? if so, what command would serve this?

Comment: Normally you can kill a query in  status "Copying to tmp table" without any kind of problem... before can you post your sql statement for that query?

Comment: Hi @Cristian Porta,

I used command 'KILL' to kill that process and everything is unlocked and released after a minute.

****THANK YOU VERY MUCH***** For helping me on this, you really save my day. I do really appreciate this. Thanks again :)

Comment: Don't mention it, BTW I think you have to follow my advice/update in the answer ;)